# How much runway does an amphibious Cessna Caravan require for VFR part 135 operations?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-performance, far-135, cessna-208

I am trying to determine the length required for us to build a simple paved runway for a Cessna Grand Caravan EX Amphibian to depart for water landings and and return (VFR/VMC only, Part 135).

Previous questions about for "runway length required" only refer to Part 135 and Part 91 for Large Transport Category.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the owners/operators of the airplanes you are building the runway for?

Comment: P.S.  I have performance charts for the wheeled 208 Caravan, if you needed a specific zero wind landing distance, or takeoff and distance needed to clear a 50 obstacle at a given weight, I could give you a number.  But you'd still need to figure out what kind of safety margin you desire.  I think the answer is probably too complex for this forum, but I can tell you that the wheeled Caravans I fly regularly service a 2900' sea level airfield at max weights without issue.  Bigger is always better though, how much space do you have?

Answer (score -1):

The minimum required runway length for a Cessna Caravan is *762m/2500ft. Considering that the Caravan has a stall speed of 60 knots, and for a safety margin, you would approach at 70 knots, this makes sense. Assuming that it slows at a rate of around 1 knot/ 10m, You can do some basic calculations: 70/1, which is 70, resulting in a 700m long runway, plus 62m for a safety margin.

EDIT: But now we're talking about amphibious, so water could help the plane slow down, but at the same time a longer takeoff roll would be required. And it turned out that the website I used wasn't reliable. Sorry about that. Anyways, it is said that an amphibious Cessna Caravan needs a takeoff roll of 2,341 feet/714m. However, the actual requirements force a 3660ft/1116m runway. I didn't get the landing distance required, but I think it's safe to say that the landing would be shorter than the takeoff roll.

*the actual runway length required of a normal caravan is 2,055 feet/ 626m, and you can expect to rotate at 1,160 ft/ 354m.

*Some (incorrect) information was from: http://www.sgl.com/208.html
And more correct info from: https://cessna.txtav.com/en/turboprop/caravan

Please tell me if I should delete the first paragraph.

Comment: This seems a little high compared to [a C208 POH](https://www.redskyventures.org/doc/cessna-poh/Cessna_208_C208B-G1000_Grandcaravan_POH-PIM_2008.pdf), which gives 1,795' over a 50' obstacle. I don't know how amphib gear changes the numbers though.

Comment: -1 because this relies on several inappropriate assumptions.

Comment: @pericynthion: none of my assumptions should be deemed appropriate, but I did forget he was talking about amphibious Caravans, not just Cessna Caravans in general. But I'm still pretty sure someone edited it to amphibious, because I didn't remember that being there.

Comment: @pericynthion: pls remove the downvote if I made the correct corrections, and tell me exactly where I went wrong so I can improve.

Comment: @Pondlife: That seems to be very odd. I don't know why a POH would have such a dramatic difference, but it is smaller. That still doesn't explain why the stall speeds are the same. Very odd.